# Can I access lifelog API (java) and collect data (in background) every hour

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

My need is to get data of say 10 `lifelog` users (example my project teammates )
I want to analyse their data and do some scoring to create fitness competition within my team.

If I have all these life log ID and password 
Will I be able to read the data from a java application and save it all in one DB?
I will analyze these data and provide score and targets.

Finally :
I will have a separate mobile app that will be using the  data from my java application.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the way to get the data from your teammates is by authenticating them with your app:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/authentication/

Once they have authenticated with your app then you can use the API to pull data to score them with.

There is not a way to take their username and password and pull data dynamically through the API.

Comment: Yes you can! Lifelog is a Web API so you can use it with any programming language that supports making http requests.

Comment: If you're looking for a Android library that makes using a REST api a little easier - look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41163606/3529903